# asp.net methods in javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have a website 
I need to find the id of my selected profile and assign that value to a variable in javascript
and show that in an alert box
where should i write the function which javascript needs to call 
in the app_code folder'class
or a web page's code file

```
var some_variable = '<%=the_method()  %>';
```

Comment: where do i need to write "the_method()" in my server side code?
moreover please tell how to pass an argument to this method which goes from client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume ASP.NET WebForms and not MVC...

if you have in your `page.aspx` a variable named:

```
public string myProfile = "profile1";
```

you will be able to pick that up in your HTML just like anything else:

```
<% Response.Write( myProfile ) %>
```

in javascript you can do the same:

```
<script>
    var myProfile = '<%= myProfile %>';
</script>
```

You can also call methods:

in your `page.aspx`

```
public string getUserName() {
    return String.Format("{0} {1}", User.fname, User.lname);
}
```

in your javascript

```
<script>
    var myProfile = '<%= getUserName() %>';
</script>
```

**Remember** that you need to decorate your variables and methods `public`ly, as if not, by default they will be `private` and not accessible from outside the scope of your code behind file.

Comment: how to pass an argument to this method which goes from client side

Comment: you can go from asp.net to javascript but not from javascript to .NET this way... you need to invoke a URL and pass the value. That tutorial you can [find in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6330501/28004) to other question. Let me know if you have any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Webservices** or **Webmethods** to communicate with the server side methods from your JavaScript code