# AJAX Request Data Is Not Present in the HttpContext object

Tags: .net, ajax, httpcontext

I am trying to send some data to a generic handler and pass that information back in the response using jQuery.ajax(). For some reason, when I send the data up based on an answer to another question I found ([.NET Simple Form Submit via AJAX and JQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330384/net-simple-form-submit-via-ajax-and-jquery)), there is nothing in the context.Request object.

Here is my ajax call:

```
function retrieveStats(monster) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MonsterRequests.ashx",
        data: { "monster": monster },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the code for my handler:

```
public class MonsterRequests : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        string monsterName = context.Request["monster"];

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("{\"d\":\"" + monsterName + "\"}");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to pull the information off by accessing the context.Request.InputStream and reading via a StreamReader, but I am curious as to why I can't just pull the info directly off of the request.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove content type as you are not sending json. Try this.

```
var monster = "value";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyHandler.ashx",
        data: { monster: monster },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function(jqXhr, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Removing the content type made it work when I send data: { "monster" : monster}. I am marking that as the answer. 

Why was it not considered json the way I had it. Also, I created and sent a JSON object (using $.parseJSON), but it still didn't show anything in the request.

Comment: By default contentType of $.ajax is
 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

See Link:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And The Form property is populated when the HTTP request Content-Type value is either "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or "multipart/form-data".


See Link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That explains it. Thanks again. :D